# dfa using switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

help sir, i'm trying to do some simple dfa but it doesn't work right. im trying to test 3 lines of input from a text file which contains, 111, 000,110. i've tried to separate them as 3 tokens but still, when it comes to testing, the program still runs it as a whole. thanks for help in advance

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class A
 {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {
    FileReader fileInput = new FileReader("B:\\input1.txt");
    BufferedReader readInput = new BufferedReader(fileInput);

    FileWriter fileOutput = new FileWriter("B:\\output.txt");
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(fileOutput);

    Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(readInput);
    int cs = 0;
    final int q0 = 0;
    final int q1 = 1;

    int noOfLines = 0;

    while(scanLine.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] tokens = scanLine.next().split("\n");

        for(String words : tokens)
        {
          outFile.println(words);
          char[] stringArray = words.toCharArray();

        for(char x : stringArray)
        {
            switch(cs)
            {
                case q0:
                    switch(x)
                    {
                        case '1':
                        cs = q1;
                        break;

                        case '0':
                        cs = q0;
                        break;

                        default:
                        outFile.println("error");
                        break;
                    }
                break;

                case q1:
                    switch(x)
                    {
                        case '1':
                        cs = q1;
                        break;

                        case '0':
                        cs = q1;
                        break;

                        default:
                        outFile.print("error");
                        break;
                    }
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }//end for char array
        outFile.println();
        noOfLines++;
        if(cs == q1)
        {
        outFile.println("accepted");
        }
        else
        {
        outFile.println("rejected");
        }//end if else
        }//end for string array
    }//end while

    outFile.println();

    fileInput.close();
    readInput.close();
    outFile.close();
    fileOutput.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is cs defined? What is it when you first enter the first switch/case?

Comment: @JBNizet dfa is abbreviation of `Deterministic Finite Automaton` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

Comment: @JonTaylor You were right I didnt notice that :).Thanks

Comment: i think it makes the 3 separate strings as one, like 111000110, where it should be 111, 000, 110

Comment: i'm actually expecting an output of accepted, rejected, accepted. but instead it gives accepted, accepted, accepted because it just tests them as a whole then printed 'accepted' 3 times.